# I want to fetch rows from mysql database with filter by near by and the limit of distance

Tags: php, mysql, location

I want to fetch rows from `MySql` database with filter by near by and the limit of distance. I have created a query that is working fine for fetching the data near by, but I want to add a condition for distance limitation, that means If I want rows which have location of 20 km distance.
This is the query that is working for near by.

```
$lat="";
$lon="";
$sql="SELECT *, 
  111.111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(".$lat."))
         * COS(RADIANS(Lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(".$lon." - Lon))
         + SIN(RADIANS(".$lat."))
         * SIN(RADIANS(Lat)))) AS d
FROM Table
ORDER BY d"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use HAVING Clause to achieve this**

```
$sql="SELECT *, 
  111.111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(".$lat."))
         * COS(RADIANS(Lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(".$lon." - Lon))
         + SIN(RADIANS(".$lat."))
         * SIN(RADIANS(Lat)))) AS d
FROM Table HAVING d <= 20
ORDER BY d"
```

Comment: (or `WHERE 111.111 * ... <=20`)